# Cron Планировщик задач

Tags: хостинг, cron, планировщик-задач

У меня хостинг на DirectAdmin стоит, и там есть такая штука как Планировщик задач. Мне нужно чтобы мой php скрипт выполнялся ежедневно в 00:00. Сам скрипт я написал, он работает, но наверное вставил не правильную ссылку на него. Файл называется cron.php. Пробовал так же такой путь: php /home/admin/домен.ком/cron.php

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

вот что написано в разделе помощи

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: вы пробывали так ../cron.php

Comment: да, только не две точки а одну ставил. сейчас попробую две поставить.

Comment: На скрипт рекомендуется выставить права доступа 755 (права на исполнение).

Comment: нет, не работает. права поставил 755

Comment: попробуйте путь такого вида : [ссылка](http://домен.ком/cron.php) с http://

Comment: Нет, не работает

Comment: ответ техподдержки можно ждать несколько дней, а проблема в том что я выставил не правильный путь

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам потребуется указать полный путь к Вашему скрипту. Например:

- Ваш логин — `user1`,
- домен — `mydomain.com`,
- в папке `public_html` находится скрипт для выполнения `mycron.php`.

Тогда команда будет выглядеть так:

```
cd /home/user1/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/; /usr/local/bin/php ./mycron.php
```

Можете также использовать вызов интерпретатора с указанием полного пути к скрипту:

```
/usr/local/bin/php /home/user1/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/mycron.php
```

Можете также использовать вызов интерпретатора определенной версии с указанием полного пути к скрипту. Например, для вызова php 5.4 используйте такой путь:

```
/usr/local/bin/php54 /home/user1/domains/mydomain.com/public_html/mycron.php
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает!

Answer (score 0):

В настройках операционной системы не указаны пути по умолчанию. Как следствие следующая команда в cron не будет выполнена.

```
php /var/www/LOGIN/data/www/SITE/cron.php
```

Правильной командой будет второй вариант, где мы пропишем полный путь до интерпретатора php.

```
/usr/bin/php /var/www/LOGIN/data/www/SITE/cron.php
```

Подробней по настройке Crone тут [Запуск PHP скрипта по расписанию cron.](https://habrahabr.ru/post/255245/)

Comment: сделал так, не работает

Comment: может отличается время? сейчас у меня например 17:10, я ставлю выполнение скрипта на 17:11, жду минуту и проверяю

Comment: Пробовал еще так: #!/usr/bin/env php /home/abmin/public_html/cron.php

Comment: Добавил новое изображение к вопросу, может поможет